# Gravity Forms Merge Tags (single field?)

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

looking to get a single field from the submitted values in the gravity form.

I would like to start the notification email to the user who submitted the form by 'Dear [name]', but the documentation doesn't seem to specify how to get single values like this from the form to the email.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the value from gravity form you have to use **Gravity Form Submit Hook**,

The sample code is like beloved,

```
add_action( 'gform_after_submission_5', 'after_submission', 10, 2 );
function after_submission(){
    // Do anything 
}
```

Here, ***5***  is your form's id, you can replace it, you can get the form submitted value in `$_POST or in $_REQUEST`, in this function.

For more information visit gravity form's official site [here.](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/)

Comment: I need it as a merge tag, I am using {[Field Name]:[field_id]} so for example {:[1]} to get the field value from field ID 1, but it's not displaying a value just the exactly '{:[1]}'

Comment: Please be clear about merge tab, you want the value of form field after submitted, then you can get into the $_POST.

Comment: I think possibly you misunderstand this is what I'm trying to use: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/merge-tags/#field-merge-tag-modifiers so I can get the value in the notification email as in "Dear name" with name being the value provided in the name form.

Answer (score 0):

{First name:1}

minus the [] characters in the documentation